# Assign or create associated model in one transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have `articles` and each article has_many `categories`.

When the user creates or updates article, he or she can fill the category name and if such category doesn't exist yet, a new one needs to be created.

**Models**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :content, :title, :category_name

  belongs_to :category

  def category_name
    category.try(:name)
  end

  def category_name=(name)
    self.category = Category.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :articles
end
```

**Controller**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @article = Article.create(params[:article])
    respond_with(@article)
  end

  def update
    @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
    @article.save
    respond_with(@article)
  end

  ...
end
```

**The problem**

On `create` or `update` actions, if the category doesn't exist yet, the new one will be created in separate transaction. So if there was an error in `article`, a new category could be created anyway.

Log of create/update actions (trimmed for brevity):

```
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" ....
   (35.1ms)  commit transaction

   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "articles" ...
   (32.2ms)  commit transaction
```

I'd like to get some advice/solution how to solve this in an elegant way.

I could probably write in my controller

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @article = Article.create(params[:article])
  respond_with(@article)
end
```

but it means I have to write the same code in both methods: `create` and `update`. Since it violates DRY principle I'd prefer to find another way.

Comment: Take a look at Railscast on [Token](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?view=asciicast). It requires some extra steps, but Ryan did great job explaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I wouldn't be concerned with 1 line of code being DRY or not.
2. you could do something like the following

Note that I don't love this, but it's doable

```
def update
  article = Article.find(params[:id])
  article.attributes = params[:article]
  respond_with persist(article)
end

def create
  article = Article.new(params[:article])
  respond_with persist(article)
end

private

def persist(article)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    return article.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but just in case if somebody is searching for a solution of a similar problem:

I think you should be able to handle it without messing with transactions and by using nested attributes as follows:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  belongs_to :category

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category

  def category_name=(name)
    category = Category.find_by(name: name)
    if category
      self.category_id = category.id
    else
      self.category_attributes = {name: name}
    end
  end
end
```

so if a category with that name exists, it will just assign the category_id. Otherwise it will assign a new category via nested attributes that will ensure the category getting persisted if there are no other validation errors for the article, and not getting persisted if there are.